# Mixing Whey + BCAA + Glutamine

Tags: bcaa, whey

I'm currently taking my Whey with additional BCAA and Glutamine powders.
Some people are skeptical about the benefits, I tested it myself, and for me it works.

I'm a little in doubt with one certain aspect of this mix. Can I mix the ingredients in a small container, and keep it, like a week?
Are there any chemical reactions between the BCAA, Glutamine and Whey, when store them together in one container? Instead of keep them separately and only mix them together, right before drinking?

In my opinion, since the three components are all dry powders, I think there is no chemical reaction. But still I'm curious if anyone knows the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should be good to go for mixing. They sell some BCAA + Glutamine powders already and adding in whey to the mix shouldn't cause any reactions.

Answer (score -1):

No problem. Go ahead; just make sure you use 300 ml water for a scoop of all of those mixed together.

Comment: Can you provide any reasoning for your advice? Why is it OK? Why do they need the water?

Comment: Bcz the water is required to make sure your digestive system is able to absorb it properly

Comment: It also makes sure That your kidneys don't get damaged

Comment: :) I'm saying that that's the sort of thing you need in your answer, preferably with some sort of citation or reference to a place where they explain that risk. Otherwise, your answer boils down to, "No, Dude, trust me, it's safe"

Comment: Okay bro got it